spring aop @annotation not works on composed annotation
For example
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A1 {}


@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@A1
public @interface A2 {}

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(A1)")
    public void pointcut() {}
    
    @Before("pointcut()")
    public void before(JoinPoint point) {
        System.out.println("before run");
    }
}

@Service
public class MyService {

    @A1
    public void test1() {}

    @A2
    public void test2() {}
}

then, call test1() will got log, but call test2() will not got any log
how can I intercept methods annotated with @A2?
I have tried @Pointcut("@annotation(A1) || @annotation(A2)"), both test1() and test2() can print out logs, but how about more annotations with @A1?
updated:
For example
I have a new annotation @A3 like
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@A1
public @interface A3 {}

then, my Aspect class should modified again
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(A1) || @annotation(A2) || @annotation(A3)")
    public void pointcut() {}
    
    @Before("pointcut()")
    public void before(JoinPoint point) {
        System.out.println("before run");
    }
}

Is there a way to intercept methods annoted by @A1 or @A2 or @A3... ?

Your question is unclear, unfortunately. Please edit and clarify what "how about more annotations with @A1?" is supposed to mean.

if I create more new annotations like
@A1
public @interface A3 {}

I should modify the @Pointcut to @Pointcut("@annotation(A1) || @annotation(A2) || @annotation(A3)"), it's too much trouble to do so

This question is a duplicate, which I already answered here, explaining how to match meta annotations on methods. Related is this answer about meta annotations on classes.
